# Restructuring massive excel document

Tags: excel, vba

I have a task to restructure a two column excel sheet and expand it. Here is a picture to show what needs to be done, the data on the left of the green column is the original data and the data on the right is how it should look, but its only done for the first entry, I need to replicate it for all 10,000 rows of data.

[image: Here]

To explain more indepth, each CRD it needs to be expanded to 160 rows, and go from 1978->2018 while listing the quarters out for each year. What is the best approach? Is it possible to write a macro to solve this ?

Comment: You can use VBA for this -  likely it could also be done using formulas.  Did you try either of those?

Comment: My first thought was a pivot table; but I have no idea where your year, quarter etc comes from.  Not enough info to understand/address the question imo.  But mabe those are in A-L... if so... then the data is already structured you just need to re-arrange the columns and apply a specific sort sequence?

Comment: @xQbert the year and quarter data is not in the document, its just going to be added to each entry but follow the same pattern for each

Comment: The Year/Qtr should go from 1978/4 thru 2018/1, and exclude other qtrs in those boundary years?  and numericalQtr always goes from 1 thru 160 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following expects Sheet1 ans Sheet2 to be the names.  And goes for 158 quarters.

```
Option Explicit

Sub doFromThru()

    ' clear contents
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A1").Select
    Cells(1, "A") = "CRD"
    Cells(1, "B") = "Year"
    Cells(1, "C") = "Quarter"
    Cells(1, "D") = "QuarterNumerical"
    Cells(1, "E") = "Disclosure"
    Dim nOutRow As Integer
    nOutRow = 1

    ' step thru all the rows on the input sheet
    Dim nInRow As Long, maxInRow As Long, nInCRD As String, nInDisc As String
    maxInRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For nInRow = 2 To maxInRow
        nInCRD = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(nInRow, "A")
        nInDisc = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(nInRow, "L")

        ' create the new rows on Sheet2
        Dim dFrom As String, nQtr As Integer
        dFrom = DateValue("Oct 1978")  ' starting from here
        For nQtr = 1 To 158
            nOutRow = nOutRow + 1

            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(nOutRow, "A") = nInCRD
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(nOutRow, "B") = Format$(dFrom, "yyyy")
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(nOutRow, "C") = Format$(dFrom, "Q")
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(nOutRow, "D") = nQtr
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(nOutRow, "E") = nInDisc

            dFrom = DateAdd("Q", 1, dFrom)
        Next nQtr

    Next nInRow

End Sub
```

Add some diagnostics to tell you more.  After  nOutRow = nOutRow + 1

```
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, "G") = nInRow
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, "H") = nOutRow
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, "I") = nQtr
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, "J") = nInDisc
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I had to change nOutRow to a 'long' and It works for the most part except once it gets to around 100,000 rows it times out at " Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(nOutRow, "A") = nInCRD". Any idea why? Thanks so much

Comment: @RyanVisek see changes above-- it may be data dependent, or if near row 65,000 it may have to do with which version of excel is being used.

Comment: I ran that and in the cells it has "6638, 1048577, 88 ,>0 Legacy"
It looks like its going over the limit of cells?

Comment: @RyanVisek 1,048,576 is max number of ROWS in excel 2016.  You might click the check mark to indicate this as a solution, even though the data would probably be better suited in a database (MSAccess or MSSQLServer or etc).

Answer (score 0):

Untested.

- Code assumes you want to start from Q4 of the year 1978 and will loop
  for 159 quarters after 1978 Q4. (If necessary, you can change this by changing the value of `TOTAL_QUARTERS` and `START_QUARTER` in the code)
- You will need to change `"Sheet1"` in the code to whatever the name of your sheet is.
- Code tries to overwrite the contents of columns `CH` to `CL` on said sheet. So you might want to save a copy of your workbook before running.

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExpandRows()

Const START_YEAR as long = 1978
Const START_QUARTER as long = 4
Const TOTAL_QUARTERS as long = 160

With thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim lastRow as long
lastRow = .cells(.rows.count, "A").row

Dim inputCRD() as variant
inputCRD = .range("A2:A" & lastRow).value2

Dim inputDisclosure() as variant
inputDisclosure = .range("L2:L" & lastRow).value2

Dim yearOffset as long
Dim quarterIndex as long
Dim numericalQuarterIndex as long

Dim totalRowCount as long
totalRowCount = (lastRow - 1) * TOTAL_QUARTERS ' -1 to skip first row

Dim outputArray() as variant
Redim outputArray(1 to totalRowCount, 1 to 5)

Dim readIndex as long
Dim writeIndex as long

For readIndex = lbound(inputCRD,1) to ubound (inputCRD,1)

quarterIndex = START_QUARTER

For numericalQuarterIndex = 1 to TOTAL_QUARTERS

writeIndex = writeIndex + 1

outputArray(writeIndex, 1) = inputCRD(readIndex, 1)
outputArray(writeIndex, 2) = START_YEAR + yearOffset
outputArray(writeIndex, 3) = quarterIndex
outputArray(writeIndex, 4) = numericalQuarterIndex
outputArray(writeIndex, 5) = inputDisclosure(readIndex, 1)

If quarterIndex < 4 then
quarterIndex = quarterIndex + 1
Else
yearOffset = yearOffset + 1
quarterIndex = 1
End if

Next numericalQuarterIndex

Next readIndex

.range("CH2").resize(ubound(outputArray,1), ubound(outputArray,2)).value2 = outputArray

End with

End sub
```